# URLjava.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411 in JAVA

Tags: java

I'm checking whether internet is available or not

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.google.co.in/");
            final HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // set connect timeout.
            conn.setConnectTimeout(1000000);

            // set read timeout.
            conn.setReadTimeout(1000000);

            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");

            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            conn.connect();

            Integer code = conn.getResponseCode();
            final String contentType = conn.getContentType();
```

While running this code i'm getting the exception

`URLjava.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 411`

What could be the error.

Comment: [Might help](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E411.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTTP status code 411 means "length required" - you've tried to make a POST request, but you've never provided any input data. The Java client code isn't setting a Content-Length header, and the server is rejecting a POST request with no length.

Why are you even trying to make a post at all? Why not make a GET request, or better yet a HEAD?

I'd also recommend that if you really need to know whether some specific site is up (e.g. a web service) that you connect to that, rather than just to Google.

Comment: i set conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length","500000"); still same error occurs

Comment: @Arasu: But you're still not setting any data - so I wouldn't be surprised if the client code was removing the Content-Length header. Again, *why* are you trying to make a POST request?

Comment: client url should be run only once because it will count to a transaction. Sometimes client internet may down ours may not be. So we have to connect to client only when our internet is up

Comment: This is a same function where URL("http://www.google.co.in/");
the argument alone will differ. here i'm passing google url

Comment: @Arasu: Well to put it simply, you're trying to make an inappropriate POST request. Personally I would suggest finding some *harmless* operation you can make to test whether your connection to the client is available. Does it really matter whose connection is failing? The important thing is whether you can reach their system. Take Google out of the picture, and make a request which *doesn't* affect transactions etc.

Comment: @Arasu: It's still not clear why you want to test for a connection to Google, when the only important connectivity is with the target of your later POST request, isn't it?

Comment: I got `response: 411` for `GET` request. I was making a `GET` request from a __python script__ to my __django server__

Comment: @JithinPavithran: I suggest you ask a new question showing a [mcve].

Answer (score 5):

Try to add the following lines to your code, that might help you understand the problem a bit better :

```
 conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
```

Do check what your inputStream from your **HTTP ERROR 411** states by adding this code :

```
InputStream is = null;
if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) 
{
    is = conn.getErrorStream();
} 
else 
{
    is = conn.getInputStream();
}
```

Hopefully that might help.

Regards

Comment: Must set allowRestrictedHeaders to true after the Application launch first: System.setProperty("sun.net.http.allowRestrictedHeaders", "true");

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following line in the code where post is performed worked:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "0");
```

Answer (score 0):

POST/ PUT should be use when modifying or creating a new instance on the back-end.
When using REST call in the form on http://///{parameter1}/{parameter2} (and so on), no query or body send! still it should be POST call if it modifying the data.

So, in this case we can do some Reflection.

```
String urlParameters = url.getQuery();
if (urlParameters == null) urlParameters = "";

byte[] postData = urlParameters.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
int postDataLength = postData.length;
if (postDataLength > 0) {
//in case that the content is not empty
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength));
    } else {
        // Reflaction the HttpURLConnectioninstance
        Class<?> conRef = conn.getClass();
        // Fetch the [requests] field, Type of MessageHeader 
        Field requestsField= conRef .getDeclaredField("requests");
        // The [requests] field is private, so we need to allow accessibility
        requestsField.setAccessible(true);
        MessageHeader messageHeader = (MessageHeader) requestsField.get(conn);
       // Place the "Content-Length" header with "0" value
        messageHeader.add("Content-Length", "0");
       // Inject the modified headers
        requestsField.set(conn, messageHeader);
    }
```

In this way we don't harm the existing model and the call will be sent with the ZERO length header.

Answer (score 0):

I passed an empty object `"{}"` in the body this fixed it.

```java
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlString).openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
OutputStreamWriter writers = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
writers.write("{}"); //body
writers.flush();
```

instead of this you can set `Content-length` as 0 also as suggested in other answers.